# Integral of square of inverse of CDF

Tags: probability-theory, definite-integrals, upper-lower-bounds, cumulative-distribution-functions

Suppose $X$ is some non-negative random variable with $\mathbb{E} X^2<\infty$ and that $F$ is its cumulative distribution function, with generalized inverse $F^{-1}$. I'm wondering how we might be able to bound the integral $\int_0^{1/2}(F^{-1}(1-x))^2dx.$

If we have a $k$-th moment for $k>2$, then I can use Markov's inequality to show that
$$F^{-1}(1-x)\leq ||X||_k/x^{1/k}$$
and hence
$$\int_0^{1/2}(F^{-1}(1-x))^2dx \leq ||X||_k^2 \int_0^{1/2} 1/x^{2/k}dx<\infty.$$
The problem with filling in $k=2$ is that the final integral in the bound is no longer finite.

How could I solve this problem (if it is even possible)?

Answer (score 3):

I will assume that $F$ is continuous and strictly increasing to simplify things. If you need a result for more general $F$, you will need to figure that out on your own.

Using [this trick for integrating inverse functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_of_inverse_functions#Statement_of_the_theorem), you get
$$
\int_{0}^{1/2}(F^{-1}(1-x))^2\,dx
=\frac12 F^{-1}(1/2)^2+\int_{F^{-1}(1/2)^2}^\infty (1-F(x^{1/2}))\,dx
$$
Using the substitution $x=u^2,dx=2u\,du$, this becomes
$$
\frac12 F^{-1}(1/2)^2+\int_{F^{-1}(1/2)}^\infty 2u(1-F(u))\,du
$$
Write $m=F^{-1}(1/2)$, which is the median of $X$. Using the same Fubini trick which proves $E[X^2]=\int_0^\infty 2tP(X>t)\,dt$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac12 m^2+\int_{m}^\infty 2uP(X>u)\,du
&=\frac12m^2+\int_m^\infty 2uE[{\bf 1}(X>u)]\,du
\\&=\frac12m^2+E\left[\int_m^X2u\,du\right]
\\&=\frac12m^2+E[(X^2-m^2)\cdot {\bf 1}(X>m)]
\\&=E[X^2\cdot {\bf 1}(X> m)]
\end{align}
$$
This is an exact expression for your integral, which also comes with the simple bounds
$$
E[X^2]-\frac12m^2\le E[X^2\cdot {\bf 1}(X> m)]\le E[X^2]
$$